# methods running on different threads WPF UI

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, thread-safety

I need to be thread safe on my app, how do you recommend to design the code?
I want that `method1` will run every 5 sec and connect to the DB, and that on `OnclickButton(object sender ,event e)` will connect the DB.

It goes like this:

```
method1()
{
    // connect db
    // do something
} 
OnclickButton(object sender,event e)
{
    // connect db
    // do something 2
}
```

Thanks guys

Comment: How will retrieved data from DB will be handled?

Comment: Your question greatly depends on what you're going to do with those database connections. If for example you're only reading from them - then it's already thread safe.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's bit broad, but in my opinion you are need 2 options:

1. Use [MVVM pattern](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/819294/WPF-MVVM-step-by-step-Basics-to-Advance-Level) which is standard de facto for WPF apps. You can use on of the many MVVM libraries like [MVVM light toolkit](http://www.mvvmlight.net/). It will help you to separate your presentation logic and business logic.
2. Good, after first step you will have `ViewModel` with binded data which can updated from `Model` or initiate actions. Your `ViewModel` can get data from the `Model` in the async-manner and updates own properites in the UI-thread. If you are using [Asynchronous Programming with Async and Await](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) you can just continue to use your code if your methods initiates from UI thread. If you are using "old-style" asynchronous programming then you can use [`Dispatcher`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) class to update bindable properties in the UI thread:

   ```
   var newUsername = model.GetUserName(); // background thread
   Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
       new Action(() => this.UserName = newUsername));
   ```